# Days_between SQL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, between, days

I'm stuck with a `days_between` function in SQL Server. I'm getting the following error

> 'days_between' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: He said MS SQL. So this question should be properly tagged as SQL-server

Comment: there is no built in function like days_between in ms-sql. you can try with DateDiff function like example DATEDIFF(DAY, '1/1/2017', '3/1/2017')

Answer (score 1):

there is no built in function like days_between in ms-sql. you can try with DateDiff function like example

```
  select DATEDIFF(DAY, '1/1/2017', '3/1/2017')
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL (SQL server), Days_between does not exist

Use [datediff](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/datediff.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is no **days_between** function is **SQL SERVER**.

What you should use is **DATEDIFF** something like this :

```
print datediff(DAY, '1/10/2017', '2/10/2017')
```

This will result in :

```
31
```

Answer (score 0):

`days_between` is not a built in SQL function (as the error explains). You'll need to use `DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate)` instead.